# Swift: Background App Refresh Task - how to view if task is running successfully

Tags: swift, background-task

I've added a background refresh task to my app as follows:

In app del:

```
func saveProductsToCD(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let queue = OperationQueue()
    
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    queue.addOperation {
        API.client.call(.products, expecting: [Product].self) { (result, products) in
            switch result {
            case .failure:
                print("Unable to retrieve products")
            case .success:
                guard let productResponse = products else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    for product in productResponse {
                            product.mapToCoreData()
                        }
                    }
                    appDelegate.saveContext()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
   BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.eHandshake.fetchAirports", using: nil) { (task) in
        self.saveProductsToCD(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
    }
```

So essentially I call an endpoint which provides me with a list of products and then I map these to my core database. I know this method works when called in the app so presume it will here.

However, what I wondered is how I can check that this is being triggered and that it is working correctly. Are there any ways to view the bg tasks that have been carried out?

Comment: Can't you just use logging to display returned data - similar to how you did the `print`, except print is not recommended for production apps.

Comment: Yeah this is the thing I don’t think print statements will cut it, especially as by the nature of these tasks u won’t be running the app when these are executed :/

Comment: Not sure how are you planning to run background task while app is not running. But look at either `os_log` or `OSLog` (iOS 14) - it's recommended way to log, has no perf penalty, and you can see it via XCode, and Console

Comment: sorry yes that was badly put, obviously app will be running in background, I meant to say tasks won't be run whilst app is in the foreground